# Is it safe to modify/remove a __dunder__ method from existing class object?

Tags: python, datamodel

I have a crazy lazy-loading hack in mind where a datamodel hook should be removed from a type at runtime (impacting all instances). This works correcly/as expected:

```py
>>> class Crazy: 
...     def __getattr__(self, attr): 
...         del Crazy.__getattr__ 
...         return 'world' 
... 
>>> c = Crazy() 
>>> c.hello 
'world'
>>> c.hello 
AttributeError: 'Crazy' object has no attribute 'hello'
```

I recall that resolution of dunder names monkeypatched onto an *instance* is not possible in Python, but am not sure if dynamically modifying dunder names of a *type* has any pitfalls.

Is this behavior guaranteed/reliable in Python?

Comment: What advantages do you intend to gain from removing the method instead of setting an instance variable flag to dictate the behavior of the method after the first execution?

Comment: It should remove the magic (after the magic has served its purpose) and just appear to be a plain old object again.

Comment: Monkeypatching an instance fails because lookups are performed on the class, not the instance. Here, you are operating directly on the class.

Comment: As far as this goes, it looks fine. I'n hesitant to comment further without knowing more about the specific context in which you want to remove an attribute.

Comment: Any comment from downvoter?

Comment: I'm sure this isn't thread-safe; whether that's a problem in your codebase is another question. I assume `__getattr__` is just an example, but if it is actually your target, I'd be concerned about accidental triggers, although again it's hard to say whether that's a practical issue. I think a bit more context would indeed be helpful.

Comment: @JacobIRR The advantage would be removing the cost of having to check for that instance variable on each and every subsequent invocation.  So, delayed initialization until time of first use but without the cost of the first use check persisting.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks This does not need to be thread-safe. Accidental triggers would be avoided by checking what name the attr is, but I left it out in order to keep the example minimal.